# C++ partial constructors with and without a body behave differently

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, raii

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DUMP(_, str) do {                      \
    std::cout << str;                          \
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)               \
        std::cout << (_).x[i] << std::endl;    \
    std::cout << "a = " << (_).a << std::endl; \
    std::cout << "b = " << (_).b << std::endl; \
    std::cout << "c = " << (_).c << std::endl; \
    std::cout << "d = " << (_).d << std::endl; \
    std::cout << std::endl;                    \
} while (0)

//#define ENABLE_WTF

struct A {
    int x[10];
    float a, b, c, d;

#ifndef ENABLE_WTF
    A() : d(4) { DUMP(*this, "=== INSIDE CTOR ===\n"); }
#else
    A() : d(4) {}
#endif
};

int main() {
    A a;
    DUMP(a, "=== OUT OF CTOR ===\n");
}
```

As can be seen, `A` has a partial constructor that only initializes one of the fields, whereas all the other fields predictably remain garbage; [demonstration here](http://cpp.sh/5zusj).

And now the question: Is it compiler-specific to zero-out the rest of `A` when its partial constructor has no body ([demonstration here](http://cpp.sh/5kmjx)), or is that a part of C++ itself?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/ysUqYG

Comment: I commented/uncommented it many times with different compilers and command line options and never saw all zeros.

Comment: @Evg Hm, so it seems like the compiler I\`m currently using (ICPC 19.0) just happens to behave similarly to the one cpp.sh runs on. Mea culpa, I haven`t considered that possibility, thus wrongly deeming such behaviour universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given constructor

```
A() : d(4) { ... }
```

all data member except `d` will be default-initialized. For built-in types this is no-op, and these data members will have indeterminate values. Reading their values is undefined behavior.

Some compilers [might initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new) such data members in debug builds with specific byte patterns to help catch runtime bugs.